# how do I solve build and run error in this code of C using CodeBlocks?

Tags: c

I am new to programming world and started with C and i want to build and run this code but it says error or multiple main function, the code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int age;

  printf("I got %d%% on my C exam\n",98);

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: What operating system and IDE are you using? What is the command line that you typed in? What is the **exact** error message?

Comment: @SanjayManohar I bet for *CodeBlocks* but I'm not sure

Comment: You might be compile multiple files in a project, which have main function in each file. Most importantly, it is not recommended to use an heavy IDE for new comers of C, use a editor instead, and compile on the command line, so that you know what exactly is happening to your program.

Comment: @fluter well, maybe.  Unfortunately, that results in SO posts because the command-line debugger tool/s are just not as easy to use as an integrated debugger.  Result - the huge majority of posts with no aparrent debug effort at all shown.

Comment: @fluter  how do i compile at the command prompt?

Comment: @N.Nadir what's your compiler?

Comment: @fluter i am using CodeBlocks

Comment: @SanjayManohar i am on windows 7 64 bit

Comment: @N.Nadir try  gcc -Wall prog.c -o prog for a start.

Comment: thanx i will try but can you tell me what is causing this error on CodeBlocks @fluter

Comment: @N.Nadir like I said above, multiple files building together? we can only guess without knowing your environment and setups.

Comment: @fluter Codeblocks isn't exactly a heavy IDE, it is one of the more beginner-friendly tools out there. Just download it and you get compiler and debugger pre-configured. You could do a lot worse.

Comment: @Lundin okay, s/heavy/light/

Comment: IN IDE is extemely useful for a beginner - the debugger is easier to use etc.  Of course, it's different for an experienced user - then IDE then becomes extemely useful to cut down on debugging time.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, the problem here is just lacking of details of the setup and errors, makes this impossible to help, it's not about use of IDE.

Answer (score 1):

You probably created a default project with an existing C source file containing a `main`, then you probably added a new file to type your code that contains a `main`, and then the IDE complains when compiling because you have two mains. Remove the default file from the project.

Comment: I think the error is in line 5. The parameter should be `9` not `98`.